# QObject retunrs with exception even after the copy constructor being declared

Tags: qt, copy-constructor, qobject

I am trying to write a sample code for qt script. I thought I am doing the right thing when I declare the `QObjecy` with the copy construtor and I also took the liberty to declare the `=` operator. But this code keeps giving me the

```
'QObject::QObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QObject'
```

Error.

I am declaring a `MyClass` which is a `QObject` as follows. I am aware of the fact that this can some one see what I am doing a wroing here.

The header:

```
#ifndef SCRIPT_CLASSES_H
#define SCRIPT_CLASSES_H
#include "QObject"
#include "QtScript/QScriptValue"
#include "QtScript/QScriptable"
#include "QtScript/QScriptClass"

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
//    Q_PROPERTY( int _id WRITE setId READ id )
public :
    MyClass(QObject *aparent =0) ;
    ~MyClass();

//     bool operator =(MyClass obj);

public slots:
    void setId(int d);
    int id() const ;
//    bool MyClass::equals(const MyClass &other);
private :
    int _id;
};

class QScriptEngine;
class Script_Classes : public QObject, public QScriptClass
{
public:
    Script_Classes(QScriptEngine *engine);
    ~Script_Classes();
private :
    static QScriptValue myClassToScript(QScriptEngine *engine,const MyClass &in);
    static void myClassFromScript(const QScriptValue &object, MyClass &out);
};

#endif // SCRIPT_CLASSES_H
```

And my source class is as follows:

```
#include "script_classes.h"
#include "QMetaType"
#include "QtScript/QScriptEngine"
#include "QtScript/QScriptValue"

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass*)

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *aparent) : QObject (aparent){}

MyClass::~MyClass(){}

void MyClass::setId(int d){
    _id = d;
}


int MyClass::id() const{
   return _id;
}

bool MyClass::equals(const MyClass &other)
{
    return id() == other.id();
}

bool MyClass::operator =(MyClass obj){
    return id()==obj.id();
}



Script_Classes::Script_Classes(QScriptEngine *engine):QObject(engine),QScriptClass(engine)
{
    qScriptRegisterMetaType<MyClass>(engine, myClassToScript, myClassFromScript);
    MyClass testClass(this);
}

void Script_Classes::myClassFromScript(const QScriptValue &object, MyClass &out){
out.setId(object.property("id").toInt32());
}

QScriptValue Script_Classes::myClassToScript(QScriptEngine *engine, const  MyClass &in)    
{
    QScriptValue value = engine->newObject();
    value.setProperty("id", in.id());
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot copy a `QObject`. From the [`QObject`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qobject.html) documentation:

> **QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.**
>   This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private
>   section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes
>   derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare
>   their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private. The
>   reasoning is found in the discussion on Identity vs Value on the Qt
>   Object Model page.
>
> The main consequence is that **you should use pointers to QObject (or to
>   your QObject subclass) where you might otherwise be tempted to use
>   your QObject subclass as a value.** For example, without a copy
>   constructor, you can't use a subclass of QObject as the value to be
>   stored in one of the container classes. You must store pointers.

Also `QObject` has not the `==` implemented so you cannot compare two instance of your class.

**PS** What is the point of overloading the `=` operator and making it operate like the `==` one? This makes your code obfuscated and debugging much more complex.

**EDIT**

Assume you have the following simple class inheriting from `QObject`

```
class A : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     int anInt;
     double aDouble;
}
```

Assume now that you want to create two inctances of `A` somewhere in your code.

```
A a1;
A a2;
```

It is illegal to call `a1=a2` since `QObject's` `=` operator is not public. What you need to do in order to achieve the copying of the data is to do it manually :

```
a2.anInt = a1.anInt
a2.aDouble = a1.aDouble
```

On the other hand if you used pointers it is totally legal to point at the same object

```
A* a1 = new A;
A* a2 = new A;
a1 = a2;
```

Now both `a1` and `a2` point at the same memory location and have the same data. If you want to have two different objects you could create a constructor with argument a pointer to the object. For our simple class you could have:

```
A::A(A* a)
{
   anInt = a->anInt;
   aDouble = a->aDouble;
}
```

and now it is legal do:

```
A a1;
A a2(&a1);
```

If you wonder why `QObject` does not allow assignment read the [Identity vs Value](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/object.html#identity-vs-value) part of the Object Model documentation.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for the quick response. I am still confused though. you said that "You should use pointers to QObject". I thought thats what I was doing my declaring " MyClass(QObject *aparent =0) ;" Isn't it. Please bare with me and give me a simple example or point me to a simple example on this. I ve tried googling on this and everything says the same thing that you suggest but I do not understand how to do it in practice. Overloading the = was a desperate measure to implement the copy constructor since it said that it is not provided in the QObject.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you. This is more than a help.. Thank you very much...